# Get weekdays in order by locale

Tags: android, calendar, locale, dayofweek, java-time

I'm trying to see if we can get the weekdays in order by locale. For example in US locale, we'll start with Sunday, while FR will start with Monday (in the terms of Calendar). To make sense out of it, I'm making an alarm app with the weekdays where the alarm is repeated on certain days -

[image]

Here are weekdays are not in ordered that I'm seeing in

```
new DateFormatSymbols().getShortWeekdays();

0 = ""
1 = "Sun"
2 = "Mon"
3 = "Tue"
4 = "Wed"
5 = "Thu"
6 = "Fri"
7 = "Sat"

0 = ""
1 = "dim."
2 = "lun."
3 = "mar."
4 = "mer."
5 = "jeu."
6 = "ven."
7 = "sam."
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### java.time

```
public static void printWeekdays(Locale loc) {
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(loc);
    DayOfWeek day = wf.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    for (int i = 0; i < DayOfWeek.values().length; i++) {
        System.out.println(day.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, loc));
        day = day.plus(1);
    }
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    printWeekdays(Locale.US);
```

The output from this call is:

> ```
> Sun
> Mon
> Tue
> Wed
> Thu
> Fri
> Sat
> ```

Or in French:

```
    printWeekdays(Locale.FRANCE);
```

Now Monday/lundi comes first, and in French, of course:

> ```
> lun.
> mar.
> mer.
> jeu.
> ven.
> sam.
> dim.
> ```

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: That worked! thank you for answering this question quickly.

Comment: This is an idiomatic way of solving it. Actually, I landed here from https://stackoverflow.com/q/74159975/10819573